# Json over Socket with Jackson

Tags: java, json, sockets, jackson

I'm trying to make two applications communicate over TCP with JSON-based messages. For that I'm using the Jackson library (1.9.4). The client side just opens a socket and then listens to all the incoming messages from the server. It looks like this:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().configure(
            Feature.AUTO_CLOSE_SOURCE, false);
final ObjectReader reader = mapper.reader(Message.class);

Socket s = new Socket("192.168.1.102", 32000);
final Reader in = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
while (true) {
    Message message = reader.readValue(in);
    process(message)
}
```

So the reader blocks and waits until the message is complete to parse it and process it. 
My problem is, sometime some messages are skipped when reading. If the server sends `msg1`, `msg` and `msg3`, maybe the `msg2` is lost but the `msg3` is read with no problem.

To make it weirder, this doesn't happen all the time, but around 50%. Both client and server is monothreaded, so nobody else has access to the socket. And I know for a fact that the messages arrive, I tried simulating the client with `nc` and the incoming messages are always correct, so I know it's when reading.

Since the it's a TCP socket, the order in which they arrived is guaranteed, so I suspect that the the `ObjectReader` is silently discarding some stuff without throwing any exception.

Does anybody have a clue of what could be going on? Any thoughts are welcome! :)

Comment: What's a `reader` and what is `readValue()` ?

Comment: Reader is a ObjectReader from the Jackson library, it's the one that should read the incoming message and parse it (this is done in the readValue() method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One suggestion: don't make a Reader, just pass InputStream as is. There is no benefit to constructing a Reader, and it's slightly slower. Not sure if that helps with the issue itself, but Jackson definitely will block on reads when it has to.

However, what will most likely happen is that since underlying `JsonParser` does buffering (for performance reasons), buffered data is not returned (since there is no way to "return" data to an input stream or reader).

`JsonParser` does have methods to access such extra buffered data, but the easiest way to solve this problem is to explicitly create `JsonParser` (via `JsonFactory`), and pass that to `ObjectReader`, and not ask `ObjectReader` to create one. This way same parser will be used, and data it buffers is used. This may also be slightly faster, since there's no per-parser creation overhead.

One more alternative method: check out `ObjectReader.readValues()` (note the -s in there), which is convenient and works pretty much the same way as manually creating and passing parser.

Comment: I was reading blah blah until i realized you're the StaxMan :D I tried  reusing the JsonParser it seems to have solved the problem, thanks a lot

Comment: Cool, no problem! Maybe I should change name to `@MrJackson` :-)

Answer (score 0):

Kind of found it.

The `readValue()` method just works properly if on each call of read on the underlaying `Reader` he gets a full JSON message.

Since I was reading from a socket, it happened sometimes that the `read()` method returned less than a full message and the `ObjectReader` coulnd't handle it properly. Which is weird, because the `ReaderBasedParser` class has a `while()`  before reading, so it should return only when the whole message is there.

Will take a closer look when I have the time.

Comment: Ended up resolving the issue comprehensively?

Comment: @Garikai, couldn't say , it was a while again and with newer versions is probable not relevant anymore, sorry

Comment: No worries, ended up stitching up a solution to my problem :)